# Most frequent values by two columns SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, count

I am trying to figure out the most occurring values within a table in groups.
This is for SQL

```
Part | location | PartDesc
-----+----------+-------------
A    | 2        | Part A
A    | 2        | Part A
A    | 2        | Part A
A    | 1        | Part A
A    | 1        | Part A
B    | 1        | Part B
B    | 2        | Part B
```

So the output needs to show

```
Part | Location | PartDesc | Occurrence 
-----+----------+----------+--------------
A    | 2        | Part A   | 3
A    | 1        | Part A   | 2 
B    | 1        | Part B   | 1
B    | 2        | Part B   | 1
```

So far I have

```
Select Part, count(*) as occurrence
from table1
group by Part
order by count(*desc)
```

Comment: is this for mysql or sql server?

Comment: can you explain more what you want exaclty with some data.

Comment: Unclear question, can't understand what you want.

Comment: Hope this is clear now?

Comment: The html tags in your question are confusing.

Comment: Should be clear now.

Comment: Your question has an answer with 2 up-votes, Why you want to delete it? let it exist ;).

Comment: I've amended the answer to reflect the OP's changed question. Should be spot on now.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT 
    Part,
    Location,
    PartDesc,
    COUNT(*) AS Occurrence
FROM
    table1
GROUP BY 
    Part,
    Location,
    PartDesc
ORDER BY 
    Occurrence DESC
```

Thanks.